# React-native StackScreen. How to use same styling for all those StackScreen?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

How to make this all Stack Screen having just 1 styling, because all of them are having a same style. As you can see. Options Props having a headerStyle, headerTitleStyle, headerLeft, headerTitleAlign have a same value.

This is my file App.js

```
const MainNavigator = () => { 
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MainScreen">

                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="MagicScreen"
                        component={MagicScreen}
                        options={{
                            title: 'Magic',
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#0074C4',
                            },
                            headerTitleStyle: {
                                color: 'white',
                                fontSize: 24
                            },
                            headerLeft: null,
                            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                        }}
                    />

                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="FightingStyleScreen"
                        component={FightingStyleScreen}
                        options={{
                            title: 'Fighting Style',
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#0074C4',
                            },
                            headerTitleStyle: {
                                color: 'white',
                                fontSize: 24
                            },
                            headerLeft: null,
                            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                        }}
                    />

                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="WeaponScreen"
                        component={WeaponScreen}
                        options={{
                            title: 'Weapons',
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#0074C4',
                            },
                            headerTitleStyle: {
                                color: 'white',
                                fontSize: 24
                            },
                            headerLeft: null,
                            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                        }}
                     />


            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
};
```

I tried to find the example code on google. But still don't find the example :")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `screenOptions` prop to the `Stack.Navigator` component. It defines the default options for each screen in a stack. Something like this will work:

```js
<Stack.Navigator 
    initialRouteName="MainScreen"
    screenOptions={{
       headerStyle: {
           backgroundColor: '#0074C4',
       },
       headerTitleStyle: {
           color: 'white',
           fontSize: 24
       },
       headerLeft: null,
       headerTitleAlign: 'center',
   }}
>
```

You can then change the title for each of the screens separately.

Answer (score 0):

`Stack.Navigator` has a `screenOptions` prop that's very similar to the `options` prop on `Stack.Screen`. It can accept a hard-coded object as a value, or a function that returns an object. In your case, the function would be best because it allows you to set the header title based on the current route:

```
// ...
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="MainScreen"
  screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#0074C4',
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 24
    },
    headerLeft: null,
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
    title: route.name === "MagicScreen"
      ? "Magic"
      : route.name === "FightingStyleScreen"
      ? "Fighting Style"
      : route.name === "WeaponScreen"
      ? "Weapons"
      : "Default",
  })}
/>
```

If you don't like the big conditional chain, you could drop the function and just pass an object containing `headerStyle`, `headerTitleStyle`, `headerLeft`, and `headerTitleAlign`. Then you'd set the title in the options of each screen like you're currently doing.

Alternatively, you could create an object to function as a route name map:

```js
// ...
const routeNameMap = {
  MainScreen: "Main",
  MagicScreen: "Magic",
  FightingStyleScreen: "Fighting Style",
  WeaponScreen: "Weapons",
}
// ...
```

And in your `screenOptions` function, set `title` to `routeNameMap[route.name] || "Default"`